# auto activate plugin when theme is active

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

i have a class to activate the plugins when i set my theme to active but the class auto activate all plugins , how i can modify to activate only the plugins that i choose.

```
if ( ! class_exists( __NAMESPACE__ . '\Auto_Activate' ) ) {
    class Auto_Activate extends Plugin {
        protected $plugins = [];

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();

            $this->plugins = [
            'woocommerce/woocommerce.php',
            'ayyash-studio/ayyash-studio.php',
            'other-plugin/main-file.php',
            //...
        ];
        }

        protected function get_plugins() {
            $plugins = $this->plugins;
            $plugin  = plugin_basename( self::get( 'file' ) );
            if ( isset( $plugins[ $plugin ] ) ) unset( $plugins[ $plugin ] );
            return apply_filters( self::get( 'slug' ), $plugins );
        }

        public function action_after_setup_theme() {
            foreach( $this->get_plugins() as $plugin => $data )
                if ( in_array( $plugin, array_keys( $this->plugins ) ) )
                    if ( is_wp_error( $result = activate_plugin( $plugin, ! empty( $data['Network'] ) ) ) )
                        error_log( self::get( 'slug' ) . ': ' . $result->get_error_message() );
        }

        public function filter_network_admin_plugin_action_links( $actions, $plugin ) {
            if ( plugin_basename( self::get( 'file' ) ) !== $plugin &&
                 array_key_exists( 'deactivate', $actions ) &&
                 array_key_exists( $plugin, $this->get_plugins() ) )
                unset( $actions['deactivate'] );

            return $actions;
        }

        public function filter_plugin_action_links( $actions, $plugin ) {
            if ( plugin_basename( self::get( 'file' ) ) !== $plugin &&
                 array_key_exists( 'deactivate', $actions ) &&
                 array_key_exists( $plugin, $this->get_plugins() ) )
                unset( $actions['deactivate'] );

            return $actions;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_plugins()` this function return all installed plugins.
so when your calling `activate_plugin()` in the loop it just activate all available (installed plugin). Just list your necessary plugin like below.

**NB: It doesn't install or download the plugins listed in the plugins array. It only activates them.**

```
class Auto_Activate extends Plugin {
    protected $plugins = [];

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->plugins = [
            'woocommerce/woocommerce.php',
            'ayyash-studio/ayyash-studio.php',
            'other-plugin/main-file.php',
            //...
        ];
    }
    public function action_after_setup_theme() {
        foreach( $this->plugins as $plugin ) {
            if ( ! is_plugin_active( $plugin ) ) {
                $activate = activate_plugin( $plugin, '', false, false );
                if ( is_wp_error( $activate ) ) {
                    error_log( $plugin . ': ' . $activate->get_error_message() );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also it's not recommended to activate a bunch of plugin like this. most of the time this would end with timeout or memory exhaustion error, instead this one-by-one with AJAX request form the browser.

**Edit:**

I clearly missed the deactivation link part from your question. Below class should do all you need. Code below had necessary documentation and hints that will help you farther.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Required Plugins Activator.
 *
 * This auto activates required plugins and remove deactivation links from plugins page.
 *
 * @package Pixelhive\PluginActivator
 * @version 1.0.0
 * @license GPL-3.0-or-later
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die();
}

class RequiredPluginActivator {

    /**
     * Singleton Instance Placeholder.
     *
     * @var self
     */
    protected static $instance;

    /**
     * Array of required plugin.
     * Plugin needs to be listed as slug/main-file.php format.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $required_plugins;

    /**
     * Create and returns singleton instance.
     *
     * @return self
     */
    public static function get_instance() {
        if ( null === self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Protected constructor, enforces singleton.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function __construct() {
        // Add the required plugins.
        $this->required_plugins = [
            'woocommerce/woocommerce.php',
            'ayyash-studio/ayyash-studio.php',
            'other-plugin/main-file.php',
            //...
        ];

        // if the theme doesn't dependes on the required plugin much for initial setup, it's safe to increase the priority.
        add_action( 'after_setup_theme', [ $this, 'install_plugins' ], 1 );

        // Filter plugin action links.
        foreach ( $this->required_plugins as $plugin ) {
            add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . $plugin, [ $this, 'plugin_action_links' ] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Install Required Plugins.
     *
     * This doesn't download the plugins itself, just activate already downloaded (installed) plugin
     * if it's not activated already.
     *
     * To download the plugin see the ajax function below for some idea.
     * @see wp_ajax_install_plugin()
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function install_plugins() {
        // After theme setup initializes even in frontend, but plugins install should only be handled from the backend.
        if ( ! is_admin() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( ! function_exists( 'is_plugin_active' ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
        }

        foreach( $this->required_plugins as $plugin ) {
            if ( is_plugin_active( $plugin ) ) {
                continue;
            }
            $activate = activate_plugin( $plugin, '', false, false );
            if ( is_wp_error( $activate ) && defined( 'WP_DEBUG' ) && WP_DEBUG ) {
                error_log( $plugin . ': ' . $activate->get_error_message() );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters Plugin Action Links.
     *
     * @param array $links Action links.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function plugin_action_links( $links = [] ) {
        if ( isset( $links['deactivate'] ) ) {
            // Removes deactivation link.
            unset( $links['deactivate'] );
        }

        return $links;
    }
}

// Initialize auto activator.
RequiredPluginActivator::get_instance();
```

**PS:** From you code it seems you used some kind of boilerplate, but i could not figure which, so i put necessary action and filter in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , it helped me , i edited the code and removed get plugins function , but how i can unset the deactivate action for this plugins?

Comment: @CrashPoint i have updated the answer for your comment. Check if it helps.

Comment: ,Thank you so much